# JAX-RS Obtain more data with authorization

Tags: java, security, jax-rs, glassfish-4

I am writing a RESTful web service with Java and Glassfish 4. I successfully setup a jdbc realm. I am able to lock certain URLs through the web.xml.
Now i want to have a resource which changes it´s value if the user is authorized or not. Example:

```
**Request:** 
exampleuser/information 
GET without BASIC Auth

**Response:**
username: example user
email: example@user.com

**Request:** 
exampleuser/information 
GET with BASIC Auth as exampleuser

**Response:**
username: example user
email: example@user.com
born: 1.1.1111
password: test
```

So i want to somehow check in the method if the user is authorized and based on that i want to return other information. how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html), it should help you

Comment: U're welcome. I had exactly the same issue few weeks ago, this link saved me :)